# Get typescript-eslint to detect single run mode in yarn repository

Tags: typescript-eslint

I have been running into Out Of Memory errors with typescript-eslint in a monorepo with ~20 TypeScript projects. This is a known issue and one of the mitigations is to enable single run detection with the `parserOptions.allowAutomaticSingleRunInference = true` option. This doesn't appear to ever trigger in a yarn managed repository though. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/c4310b1aac35c7d31b826f0602eca6a5900a09ee/packages/typescript-estree/src/parser.ts#L390), will this ever work? It seems like because yarn runs in a `/tmp` directory it will never match the file path to detect single run mode:

```
$ yarn exec which eslint
/tmp/xfs-3826b2c0/eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [8 lines earlier in the file you linked](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/c4310b1aac35c7d31b826f0602eca6a5900a09ee/packages/typescript-estree/src/parser.ts#L379-L382):

```
if (process.env.TSESTREE_SINGLE_RUN === 'true') {
  extra.singleRun = true;
  return;
}
```

Setting `TSESTREE_SINGLE_RUN=true` as an environment variable will force typescript-eslint to run in single run mode.

Comment: Aside: this isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs yet. I filed https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/8230 to add it. Thanks :)